# How to get name of account which is processing action recent in contract?

Tags: smart-contract, accounts, authorization

I need to authorize with admin table of contract. but I could not account name which is processing action of contract. Let me know about any eos function to get account name, if anyone know well.

```
    user = <recent account name>;
    admins admin(get_self(), user.value);   
    auto itr = admin.require_find(user.value, "not allowed");
```

Answer (score 0):

just pass the user-name as parameter and verify that it was authorized by the user:

```
ACTION somecontract::someact(eosio::name user){
    require_auth(user);
    admins admin(get_self(), user.value);   
    auto itr = admin.require_find(user.value, "not allowed");
}
```

*As a Sidenote: I don't know much about the desired functionallity behind this but usually it is unwise to use the one value as both scope and key.*